# Nondeterminism for infinite inputs

Tags: haskell, monads, non-deterministic

Using lists to model nondeterminism is problematic if the inputs can take infinitely many values. For example

```
pairs = [ (a,b) | a <- [0..], b <- [0..] ]
```

This will return `[(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),...]` and never get around to showing you any pair whose first element is not `0`.

Using the [Cantor pairing function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function) to collapse a list of lists into a single list can get around this problem. For example, we can define a bind-like operator that orders its outputs more intelligently by

```
(>>>=) :: [a] -> (a -> [b]) -> [b]
as >>>= f = cantor (map f as)

cantor :: [[a]] -> [a]
cantor xs = go 1 xs
  where
    go _ [] = []
    go n xs = hs ++ go (n+1) ts
      where
        ys = filter (not.null) xs
        hs = take n $ map head ys
        ts = mapN n tail ys

mapN :: Int -> (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
mapN _ _ []   = []
mapN n f xs@(h:t)
  | n <= 0    = xs
  | otherwise = f h : mapN (n-1) f t
```

If we now wrap this up as a monad, we can enumerate all possible pairs

```
newtype Select a = Select { runSelect :: [a] }

instance Monad Select where
    return a = Select [a]
    Select as >>= f = Select $ as >>>= (runSelect . f)

pairs = runSelect $ do
    a <- Select [0..]
    b <- Select [0..]
    return (a,b)
```

This results in

```
>> take 15 pairs
[(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(0,2),(1,1),(2,0),(0,3),(1,2),(2,1),(3,0),(0,4),(1,3),(2,2),(3,1),(4,0)]
```

which is a much more desirable result. However, if we were to ask for triples instead, the ordering on the outputs isn't as "nice" and it's not even clear to me that all outputs are eventually included --

```
>> take 15 triples
[(0,0,0),(0,0,1),(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(1,0,1),(2,0,0),(0,0,2),(1,1,0),(2,0,1),(3,0,0),(0,1,1),(1,0,2),(2,1,0),(3,0,1),(4,0,0)]
```

Note that `(2,0,1)` appears before `(0,1,1)` in the ordering -- my intuition says that a good solution to this problem will order the outputs according to some notion of "size", which could be an explicit input to the algorithm, or could be given implicitly (as in this example, where the "size" of an input is its position in the input lists). When combining inputs, the "size" of a combination should be some function (probably the sum) of the size of the inputs.

Is there an elegant solution to this problem that I am missing?

Comment: Could you possibly replace [] with logict?

Comment: Maybe! I'll take a look at how that's implemented. Am mostly interested in this for educational reasons rather than because I want to use it for something.

Comment: This is really cool; I don't know how to give it a nice monadic interface, but maybe the concept of space-filling curves can give you the behavior you want (as they can be n-dimensional)?

Answer (score 7):

TL;DR: It flattens two dimensions at a time, rather than flattening three at once. You can't tidy this up in the monad because `>>=` is binary, not ternary etc.

---

I'll assume you defined

```
(>>>=) :: [a] -> (a -> [b]) -> [b]
as >>>= f = cantor $ map f as
```

to interleave the list of lists.

You like that because it goes diagonally:

```
sums = runSelect $ do
    a <- Select [0..]
    b <- Select [0..]
    return (a+b)
```

gives

```
ghci> take 36 sums
[0,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7]
```

so it's pleasingly keeping the "sizes" in order, but the pattern appears to be broken for `triples`, and you doubt completeness, but you needn't. It's doing the same trick, but twice, rather than for all three at once:

```
triplePairs = runSelect $ do
    a <- Select [0..]
    b <- Select [0..]
    c <- Select [0..]
    return $ (a,(b,c))
```

The second pair is treated as a single source of data, so notice that:

```
ghci> map fst $ take 36 pairs
[0,0,1,0,1,2,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
ghci> map fst $ take 36 triplePairs
[0,0,1,0,1,2,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

and (adding some spaces/newlines for clarity of pattern):

```
ghci> map snd $ take 36 pairs
[0, 1,0, 2,1,0, 3,2,1,0, 4,3,2,1,0, 5,4,3,2,1,0, 6,5,4,3,2,1,0, 7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0]
ghci> map snd $ take 36 triplePairs
[(0,0),  (0,1),(0,0),  (1,0),(0,1),(0,0),  (0,2),(1,0),(0,1),(0,0), 
 (1,1),(0,2),(1,0),(0,1),(0,0), 
 (2,0),(1,1),(0,2),(1,0),(0,1),(0,0), 
 (0,3),(2,0),(1,1),(0,2),(1,0),(0,1),(0,0), 
 (1,2),(0,3),(2,0),(1,1),(0,2),(1,0),(0,1),(0,0)]
```

so you can see it's using exactly the same pattern. This doesn't preserve total sums and it oughtn't because we're getting to three dimensions by flattening two dimensions first before flattening the third in. The pattern is obscured, but it's just as guaranteed to make it to the end of the list.

Sadly if you want to do three dimensions in a sum-preserving way, you'll have to write `cantor2`, `cantor3` and `cantor4` functions, possibly a `cantorN` function, but you'll have to ditch the monadic interface, which is inherently based on the bracketing of `>>=`, hence two-at-a-time flattening of dimensions.

Answer (score 4):

A correct multidimentional enumerator could be represented with a temporary state object

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances #-}

class Space a b where
  slice :: a -> ([b], a)

instance Space [a] a where
  slice (l:ls) = ([l], ls)
  slice [] = ([], [])

instance (Space sp x) => Space ([sp], [sp]) x where
  slice (fs, b:bs) = let
      ss = map slice (b : fs)
      yield = concat $ map fst ss
    in (yield, (map snd ss, bs))
```

Here an `N` dimensional space is represented by a tuple of lists of `N-1` dimensional subspaces that have and haven't been touched by the enumeration.

You can then use the following to produce a well ordered list

```
enumerate :: (Space sp x) => sp -> [x]
enumerate sp = let (sl, sp') = slice sp
               in sl ++ enumerate sp'
```

[Example in Ideone](http://ideone.com/AV9VV0).

Comment: Why not include your output in your post so we can see how pleasingly symmetrical it is withourt clicking through and scrolling?

Comment: @chunksOf50 Because the way I construct my Space objects is too ugly for public :D.

Answer (score 4):

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Arrow

data Select a = Select [a]
              | Selects [Select a]

instance Functor Select where
  fmap f (Select x) = Select $ map f x
  fmap f (Selects xss) = Selects $ map (fmap f) xss

instance Applicative Select where
  pure = Select . (:[])
  Select fs <*> xs = Selects $ map (`fmap`xs) fs
  Selects fs <*> xs = Selects $ map (<*>xs) fs

instance Monad Select where
  return = pure
  Select xs >>= f = Selects $ map f xs
  Selects xs >>= f = Selects $ map (>>=f) xs

runSelect :: Select a -> [a]
runSelect = go 1
 where go n xs = uncurry (++) . second (go $ n+1) $ splitOff n xs
       splitOff n (Select xs) = second Select $ splitAt n xs
       splitOff n (Selects sls) = (concat hs, Selects $ tsl ++ rl)
        where ((hs, tsl), rl) = first (unzip . map (splitOff n)) $ splitAt n sls
```

> *Select> take 15 . runSelect $ do { a<‌-Select [0..]; b<‌-Select [0..]; return (a,b) }
>   [(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1),(0,2),(1,2),(2,0),(2,1),(2,2),(0,3),(1,3),(2,3),(3,0),(3,1),(3,2)]
>   *Select> take 15 . runSelect $ do { a<‌-Select [0..]; b<‌-Select [0..]; c<‌-Select [0..]; return (a,b,c) }
>   [(0,0,0),(0,0,1),(0,1,0),(0,1,1),(1,0,0),(1,0,1),(1,1,0),(1,1,1),(0,0,2),(0,1,2),(0,2,0),(0,2,1),(0,2,2),(1,0,2),(1,1,2)]

Note that this is still not quite Cantor-tuples (`(0,1,1)` shouldn't come before `(1,0,0)`), but getting it correct would be possible as well in a similar manner.

Answer (score 4):

The [omega](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/control-monad-omega/docs/Control-Monad-Omega.html) package does exactly what you want and guarantees that every element will be eventually visited:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.Omega

main = print . take 200 . runOmega $
  (,,) <$> each [0..] <*> each [0..] <*> each [0..]
```

---

Another option would be to use [LogicT](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/logict/docs/Control-Monad-Logic.html). It gives more flexibility (if you need) and has operations such as [`(>>-)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/logict-0.6.0.1/docs/Control-Monad-Logic-Class.html#v%3a-62--62--45-) that ensure that every combination is eventually encountered.

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Logic

-- | Convert a list into any MonadPlus.
each :: (MonadPlus m) => [a] -> m a
each = msum . map return

-- | A fair variant of '(<*>)` that ensures that both branches are explored.
(<@>) :: (MonadLogic m) => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
(<@>) f k = f >>- (\f' -> k >>- (\k' -> return $ f' k'))
infixl 4 <@>

main = print . observeMany 200 $
  (,,) <$> each [0..] <@> each [0..] <@> each [0..]
```